# C# AES & RSA Encryption of data sent in http post

Tags: c#, curl, encryption, openssl

I have a 3rd party service that i need to post xml data to however this data needs to be encrypted before sending. The service is Java based and my application is c sharp. i have been supplied with a pem format public key and have used the bouncy castle library to get the key from this. The documentation supplied refers to openssl and curl for encrypting the data and sending. i have coded what i believe should work however the response i am getting from the server suggests my encryption is incorrect.

Does what i am doing look correct as per the documentation?

The link to the documentation is [Encryption example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/86110783/XML%20encryption%20sample%20pack.pdf)

The example supplied is as follows

Generate new AES key and IV and store in aes_key_iv.txt – use custom password

I am told we do not need to uses a password here.

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -k p4ssw0rd -P -md sha1 > aes_key_iv.txt
```

Grab the key and store it

```
cat aes_key_iv.txt | grep "^key" | cut -d = -f 2 > aes_key.txt
```

Grab the IV and store it

```
cat aes_key_iv.txt | grep "^iv" | cut -d = -f 2 > aes_iv.txt
```

RSA encrypt AES key, Base64 encode, Strip newlines URL encode, save in `aeskeyfinal.txt`

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey pubkey.pem -pubin -in aes_key.txt | \

openssl enc -e -base64 | tr -d '\n' | \

perl -MURI::Escape -ne 'chomp;print uri_escape($_),"\n"' > aeskeyfinal.txt
```

AES encrypt XML, Base64 encode, strip newlines URL encode, save in    `urlencr_xml.txt`

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -K `cat aes_key.txt` -iv `cat aes_iv.txt` \
-in plaintext.xml | openssl enc -e -base64 | tr -d '\n' | \

perl -MURI::Escape -ne 'chomp;print uri_escape($_),"\n"' > urlencr_xml.txt
```

POST to CPF – Customise partner ID

```
curl -X POST \
-H "x-cbg-encrypted-content: true" \
-H "x-cbg-partner-id: partner_id" \
-H "x-cbg-rsa-encrypted-aes-key: `cat aeskeyfinal.txt`" \
-H "x-cbg-aes-iv: `cat aes_iv.txt`" \
--data xmlInput=`cat urlencr_xml.txt’ \
https://www.uat.i-prompt.co.uk
```

The public key is as follows, saved in c:\key.pem

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEArwPRGxD31m9GoCucD8tU
OPvacmS9J93Oj5b8OsLEzeTYgvgPnGOej3pOfU9MFtN7XZTMQvGtFapdOLe7xX3B
q7bQEXJZQalUgaGMUikKvekw3rmfPUYzKu9TW1w4SJzlqp4DTZ2Qb7M1S7XI2a2B
dK47NmW3x6squnVDVoVmcdCwSW6U3bQOKlhKLdVzvT8i0dGnswrgcI7JzvdujdsR
qycx6N+NqlKxzMZ7iQLT2/x5PQFN1pRLPc07pRq9vwPyOxLYeq+CnYklAXw1/GIo
uv4mn7dQ2ljOkExFgPi98+dQ1h5kUk63bh9RsvtT4oGuoR/3Lr37kffQZse8io5U
dQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

my code is as follows.

The main method that posts the request:

```
public void closeReq()
    {

        loan_quote_request lqr = new loan_quote_request
        {
            rate_reference = "xxx",
            broker_number = "xxxxxxxxxx",
            system_id = "xxxxxxx",
            gross_rate = "17.5",
            deposit_amount = new deposit_amount { collected_by = deposit_amountCollected_by.BROKER, Value = "50.00" },
            loan_premium = "500.00"
        };


        XmlSerializer xsResponse = new XmlSerializer(typeof(loan_quote_response));

        string xml = Class1.SerializeObject<loan_quote_request>(lqr);
        AsymmetricKeyParameter param = ReadAsymmetricKeyParameter(@"C:\key.pem");


        AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();

        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.KeySize = 256;
        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        aes.GenerateIV();
        aes.GenerateKey();

        string aesKey = Convert.ToBase64String(aes.Key);
        string aesIV = Convert.ToBase64String(aes.IV);

        string encryptedXML = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Class1.Encrypt256(xml, aes).Replace("\n",""));
        string unencryptedXML = Class1.Decrypt256(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(encryptedXML), aes);

        string x = Class1.ByteArrayToString(aes.Key);
        var y = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(x);

        string encryptedAesKey = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Class1.rsaEncrypt(aesKey, param).Replace("\n",""));


        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encryptedXML);

        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;

        Uri myUri = new Uri("https://www.uat.i-prompt.co.uk");
        WebRequest myWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(myUri);

        HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)myWebRequest;

        myWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        myWebRequest.Proxy = null;
        myWebRequest.Headers.Add("x-cbg-partner-id:" + lqr.system_id);
        myWebRequest.Headers.Add("x-cbg-encrypted-content: true");
        myWebRequest.Headers.Add("x-cbg-rsa-encrypted-aes-key:" + encryptedAesKey);
        myWebRequest.Headers.Add("x-cbg-aes-iv:"+ aesIV);



        myWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = myWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }


        WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
        loan_quote_response wr = new loan_quote_response();

        Stream s = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);

        string responseXML = sr.ReadToEnd();

        TextReader textReader = new StringReader(responseXML);
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore };

        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings);

        wr = (loan_quote_response)xsResponse.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        sr.Close();

    }
```

The encryption class

```
public static class Class1
{
    public static string SerializeObject<T>(this T toSerialize)
    {

        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");

        var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringwriter);

        writer.WriteDocType("loan_quote_request", null, "premium_finance_interface.dtd",null);

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        serializer.Serialize(writer, toSerialize, ns);

        var str = stringwriter.ToString();

        var str1 = str.Replace("<q1:", "<").Replace("</q1:", "</");

        return str;

    }

    public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
    {
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in ba)
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        return hex.ToString();
    }

    public static string rsaEncrypt(string plainTextData,AsymmetricKeyParameter pubKey)
    {
        var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);
        RsaKeyParameters rsaKeyParameters = (RsaKeyParameters)pubKey;
        RSAParameters rsaParameters = new RSAParameters();
        rsaParameters.Modulus = rsaKeyParameters.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
        rsaParameters.Exponent = rsaKeyParameters.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
        csp.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

        //for encryption, always handle bytes...
        var bytesPlainTextData = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainTextData);

        //apply pkcs#1.5 padding and encrypt our data 
        var bytesCypherText = csp.Encrypt(bytesPlainTextData, false);

        //we might want a string representation of our cypher text... base64 will do
        var cypherText = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesCypherText);

        return cypherText;
    }

    public static byte[] RSAEncrypt(byte[] data, AsymmetricKeyParameter key)
    {
        IAsymmetricBlockCipher engine = new RsaEngine();
        engine.Init(true, key);
        var blockSize = engine.GetInputBlockSize();
        return engine.ProcessBlock(data, 0, blockSize);
    }

    public static string Encrypt256(string text, AesCryptoServiceProvider aes)
    {

        // Convert string to byte array
        byte[] src = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

        // encryption
        using (ICryptoTransform encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor())
        {
            byte[] dest = encrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);

            // Convert byte array to Base64 strings
            return Convert.ToBase64String(dest);
        }
    }

    public static string Decrypt256(string text,AesCryptoServiceProvider aes)
    {

        // Convert Base64 strings to byte array
        byte[] src = System.Convert.FromBase64String(text);

        // decryption
        using (ICryptoTransform decrypt = aes.CreateDecryptor())
        {
            byte[] dest = decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);
            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(dest);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: the documentation supplied can be found here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/86110783/XML%20encryption%20sample%20pack.pdf

Comment: If only there were some kind of a standard for SSL/TLS style encryption of HTTP traffic...